# How to query postgis data by closest point and only return results for that point?

Tags: postgis

I have a postgis table of points, 460 million records. It has a timestamp & point column.

I'm building graphs based on this data, a list of values for each timestamp that belong to the closest point, leaflet sends the lat/long from the map (where the user clicked) to the script that generates the chart-ready data.

```
SELECT thevalue 
FROM thetable 
WHERE ST_DWithin (thepoint, ST_MakePoint($get_lon, $get_lat), 0.04) 
ORDER BY thedate 
LIMIT 1000
```

This works great (for some clicks) but there has to be a better/faster way, I'd like the query to know what point to listen to and only return values for that point. Is there a better function for this requirement?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What king of geometry do you have? what projection are you using?
I'm going to assume that  your points are in wgs84 (epsg:4326)

If you want distances to be accurate, it's better to use geography in calculations:

```
alter points_table add column geog geography
update points_table set geog = geom::geography
```

create an index, and run `cluster` and `analyze` to speed up queries

```
create index my_index_geog on points_table using gist(geog) /* change geog for geom if using geometry */
cluster points_table using my_index_geog
analyze points_table
```

to get the closest point:

```
SELECT point_id 
FROM points_table
ORDER BY geog <-> ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint($get_lon, $get_lat),4326)::geography limit 1;
```

all together to get the values:

```
select value
from table
where point_id = (SELECT point_id 
FROM points_table
ORDER BY geog <-> ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint($get_lon, $get_lat),4326)::geography limit 1)
order by thedate
limit 1000;
```

additionally I would suggest keeping a table that contains only the points id's and the geometry/geography so the closest-point query runs faster. If you create such table, called `only_points`, the query becomes:

```
select value
from table
where point_id = (SELECT point_id 
FROM only_points
ORDER BY geog <-> ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint($get_lon, $get_lat),4326)::geography limit 1)
order by thedate
limit 1000;
```

If you need to keep using `geometry`, then you'll need to create the index on the geometry, cluster based on `geom` and run the query:

```
select value
from table
where point_id = (SELECT point_id 
FROM points_table
ORDER BY geom::geography <-> ST_SetSrid(ST_MakePoint($get_lon, $get_lat),4326)::geography limit 1)
order by thedate
limit 1000;
```

It will be slower, however, because you'll be converting to geography on each step

see [KNN in Postgis](https://postgis.net/docs/geometry_distance_knn.html)  and [PostGIS geography type and indexes](https://postgis.net/docs/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#PostGIS_Geography)